# CodeIgniter. Page only accepts the 1st input

Tags: php, codeigniter

Take note this was just done for the sake of experimentation to headstart my journey in CodeIgniter. :D

Hello Stackoverflow. Why is it that my page only echoes the username of the given inputs? Could you please tell me on what part did I screw up??

```
<?php


$data = array(
                'name'        => 'username',
              'id'          => 'username',
                );
$data2 = array(
                'name' >= 'pw',
                'value' >= ''
    );

$data3 = array(
                'value'        => 'Submit',
                'type' >=  'submit'
                );


echo form_open();
echo form_input($data);
echo form_password($data2);
echo form_submit($data3);
echo form_close();



$hello  = $this->input->post('username');
$hello2  = $this->input->post('pw');
if(isset($hello))
{
echo $hello. " ". $hello2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because of your array and try to add some value to it

```
$data2 = array(
                'name' => 'pw',
                'value' => 'passowrd'
    );
```

change `>=` to `=>`

Comment: LOL WHAT A SILLY MISTAKE. I'm really grateful for pointing that out for me! Feels so disappointing to do those kinds of mistakes but we're just human after all. It's all fine now. :)